# Android open file I wrote to cache

Tags: android, caching, directory

I am trying to read a file I already created in the application's cache directory

yes I used File (java.io.File) to create the file in the cache directory, I use file to check to see if the created file exists

but in another class I need to open that file (a class that isn't called unless the file exists), I want to use openFileInput(String filename) but openFileInput doesn't allow file paths! it also doesn't default to the cache directory, what a conundrum! (using debugger to watch all the various exceptions that openFileInput will throw, it either gives file not found or illegal arguments when a path name is input)

I need another way to get at this file. Everything worked when I was reading and writing to storage, but I need to use cache.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use openFileInput in this instance- why not just use File methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use openFileInput(String filename) but openFileInput doesn't allow file paths!

Of course.

> it also doesn't default to the cache directory

It is not supposed to.

> I need another way to get at this file.

Use Java file I/O, the same way you created the file. As you (hopefully) used when you created the file, `getCacheDir()` returns the application's cache directory. Use the same File constructor you used to write to the file to read from the file.

Comment: Yes, I have since gotten this to work. I was confusing myself with another method earlier.